# How can I run multiple pv commands in parallel?

Tags: shell, parallelism, job-control, pv

I want to run a sequence of command pipelines with `pv` on each one. Here's an example:

```
for p in 1 2 3
do
  cat /dev/zero | pv -N $p | dd of=/dev/null &
done
```

The actual commands in the pipe don't matter (`cat`/`dd` are just an example)...

The goal being 4 concurrently running pipelines, each with their own `pv` output. However when I try to background the commands like this, `pv` stops and all I get are 4 stopped jobs. I've tried with `{...|pv|...}&`, `bash -c "...|pv|..." &` all with the same result.

How can I run multiple `pv` command pipelines concurrently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found that I can do this with `xargs` and the `-P` option:

```
josh@subdivisions:/# seq 1 10 | xargs -P 4 -I {} bash -c "dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=10000000 | pv -c -N {} | dd of=/dev/null"
        3: 7.35GiB 0:00:29 [ 280MiB/s] [                                                                                         <=>                                                                 ]
        1: 7.88GiB 0:00:29 [ 312MiB/s] [                                                                                         <=>                                                                 ]
        4: 7.83GiB 0:00:29 [ 258MiB/s] [                                                                                         <=>                                                                 ]
        2: 6.55GiB 0:00:29 [ 238MiB/s] [                                                                                         <=>                                                                 ]
```

Send output of the array to iterate over into stdin of `xargs`; To run all commands simultaneously, use `-P 0`

Comment: Also note that it's essential to add the options -c -N to pv like in the example command given here. Otherwise all 4 lines are printed one on to the other

Answer (score 4):

`pv` cannot be started in background.

As you can see in the `src/main/main.c` file from `pv`'s source code, they're
setting the `TOSTOP` flag on the terminal with `tcsetattr()` (in the `c.c_lflag` of the `termios` structure). They're doing that in order to receive a `SIGTTOU` when trying to write to the terminal when not in foreground, catch it with a signal handler, and redirect the output to `/dev/null` in order not to "mess up" the terminal.

> ```
> /*
>  * Set terminal option TOSTOP so we get signal SIGTTOU if we try to
>  * write to the terminal while backgrounded.
>  *
>  * Also, save the current terminal attributes for later restoration.
>  */
> memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
> tcgetattr(STDERR_FILENO, &t);
> t_save = t;
> t.c_lflag |= TOSTOP;
> tcsetattr(STDERR_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
> ```

This is of course gross, because it doesn't set that flag just for itself, but for all the programs using the terminal.

But that's not all. As explained in the glibc [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mode-Functions.html#Mode-Functions):

> Function: int tcsetattr (int filedes, int when, const struct termios
>   *termios-p)
>
> If this function is called from a background process on its
>   controlling terminal, normally all processes in the process group are
>   sent a SIGTTOU signal, in the same way as if the process were trying
>   to write to the terminal. The exception is if the calling process
>   itself is ignoring or blocking SIGTTOU signals, in which case the
>   operation is performed and no signal is sent. See Job Control.

They're not blocking or ignoring the `SIGTTOU`. And they're also not checking the return value of `tcsetattr()` (which would return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR` ***if*** they had set the `SIGTTOU` signal handler before).

So the process is stopped. If it receives a `SIGCONT` (as from the `bg` command), it will stop again when trying to complete the `tcsetattr()`.

So I guess you should consider it a feature ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful to understand the behavior I was seeing :)